# Can I automatically change image source after countdown expires?

Tags: javascript, image, timer, countdown

Is it possible to automatically change an image's source after a countdown/timer has reached zero? Let's say that I have 2 image sources - **A** and **B**, and one timer. How can I change the image source from **A** to **B**, when the timer has expired?

```
<img class="image" src="A">
<div class="timer"></div>
```

Timer expires:

```
<img class="image" src="B">
<div class="timer">Expired</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the src with JavaSript's `.src`.

Here's an example:

```js
var changeSrc = function() {
  document.getElementById("image").src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150";
}

var count=10;
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer() {
  count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0) {
     clearInterval(counter);
     changeSrc();
  }
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count;
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
<br>
<div>Timer: <span id="timer">10</span></div>
```